# What is the equivalent of gksudo in Kubuntu/KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, sudo

In regular Ubuntu (Unity/Gnome), I use `gksudo` to run GUI programs with root privileges. I'm trying out Kubuntu (or KDE) now -- what do I use?

Comment: This seems to be too obvious to ask&answer.

Comment: I disagree. Didn't know it before, as I've never seen the `kdesudo` command before.

Comment: similarly; I remember a [kdesu](http://www.linfo.org/kdesu.html) for some reason that is 'command not found' in 15.04 at least

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Kubuntu/KDE equivalent of *gksudo* is **`kdesudo`**. You can use this in the terminal or via the graphical command box on the top of the screen (Alt-F2).

When you do this, or otherwise launch an application which requires root privileges, you will get a *kdesudo* popup like this:

[image]

> Note: If you are not getting this box with GUI applications, it may indicate a problem with the way the KDE desktop environment was installed. Please try reinstalling `kubuntu-desktop` if you are not using Kubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

As of Kubuntu 20.04, `kdesudo` doesn't seem to be installed by default, and `kdesu` is no longer in $PATH, but in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kdesu`.

As of Fedora 38, `kdesu` is in path. The "root" password it requires is the actual password for `root`, not your user's sudo password. You can change the root password with `sudo passwd root`.

Answer (score 4):

Now it is `kdesu`,

Example, If I want to use Matlab, and I want to run it as sudo user then I would type in: `kdesu matlab`, which would open a GUI window for taking my password as input.

Comment: For whatever reason in Kubuntu bionic beaver the command wasn't added to the path, but I can run it from `/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kdesu`

Comment: @Looserof7 Since `su` and `sudo` are both command-line apps, I would imagine that `kedsu` and `kdesudo` both exist.