# Kubuntu 17.10 root access for GUI

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, root

I need to access root in Kubuntu 17.10 through graphical interface, can someone point out how this is done please. This differ since Kubuntu 17.10 uses Wayland.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of gksudo in Kubuntu/KDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165755/what-is-the-equivalent-of-gksudo-in-kubuntu-kde) and [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w)

Answer (score 0):

Install `kdesudo` if it's not installed by running

```
sudo  apt install kdesudo
```

Then you'll be able to run GUI applications as root, for example

```
kdesudo kate /path/to/file.text
```

Comment: This use to work for me but not anymore since Kubuntu 17.10

Comment: @wblm Well, you haven't mentioned that in the [initial version](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/995732/1) of your question, have you? If you had provided this info I would not have posted this answer which is of no use to you. Important details in questions always help to reduce guesswork and increase the possibility of getting most relevant answers :)